# Como acceder a un textbox desde otra clase con c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, textbox

Perdon voy a editar mi pregunta inicial para que se entienda mejor, es que soy nuevo en el foro.

Cuando creo una aplicacion en windows forms se crea una clase predeterminada llamada Mainform, luego en el editor de diseño agrego un control textbox1 y desde la clase mainform puedo escribir en el textbox1 mediante el codigo:

textBox1.text="hola mundo";

hasta ahi todo perfecto.

luego hago click derecho sobre el proyecto y agrego un nuevo elemento clase, al cual le pongo de nombre class2.

ahora lo que yo quiero hacer es que desde class2 poder usar el codigo:

textBox1.text="hola mundo";

pero no funciona.

pd: Aclaro de antemano que instancie el objeto la clase principal Mainform en class2 y tambien puse publico en modificador de acceso del textbox

Comment: Deberias llamar desde el codebehind de la vista a las clases que tienen comportamiento de tu regla de negocio. No al reves.

Comment: y desde donde piensas llamar a class2 ? porque necesitas esa class2?

Answer (score 1):

Edito la respuesta en base a tu código.

Creo que debes modificar tu código de la siguiente manera ya que entiendo que realizas el procedimiento al reves.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Class1 l = new Class1();
        Textbox1.Text = l.saludar();
    }
}
}

namespace prueba

{

public class Class1
{
    public string Saludar()
    {
        return "Hola mundo";
    }
}
```

Comment: yo queria poder escribir Textbox1.Text = "Hola mundo"; dentro de class1, pero creo que mejor lo hare como tu dices, muchas gracias ramiro por tu tiempo y por tu ayuda

Comment: Ok. Márcala como correcta.